# Formal power series and the quadratic formula

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers, formal-power-series

I was recently reviewing a derivation of getting a formula for Catalan numbers in closed form. I understand the mechanics of the derivation, with the exception of one significant step:

If $f(x) = c_0 + c_1x +c_2x^2 + \cdots $ is the generating series for the Catalan numbers $c_n, n \geq 0$, then it satisfies the relation $xf(x)^2 - f(x) + 1 = 0$. But the next step of the proof is to solve for $f(x)$ by using the quadratic formula, which gives $f(x) = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4x}}{2x}$ (and then we take the 'minus' since the 'plus' doesn't work). My question is regarding the legality of applying the quadratic formula (qf) here. We initially learn the qf in elementary algebra, which is in the context of the $\textit{field}$ of real numbers. In particular, division and square roots are permitted. Here we are working with the $\textit{ring}$ of formal power series. Specifically, not all fps have multiplicative inverses, and indeed the fps $2x$ is not invertible. I see that the idea is that the numerator (after simplification) can be seen to have a factor of $x$, and so the idea is that we simply want to 'cancel' these two factors of $x$, but this strikes me as non-rigorous. I appreciate that we can prove we get the correct answer a posteriori (since it satisfies the recurrence relation that the Catalan numbers need to satisfy), but the actual method of finding the answer seems to be informal symbol manipulation based on our intuition of the qf in a field. So I suppose my specific question is:

Why are we allowed to divide by $x$ here when $x$ is not invertible in the ring of fps?

My guess is that it is allowed due to analytic convergence of the series on some positive radius of convergence, but I am really looking for some combinatorial/algebraic reasoning instead, which could potentially generalize to other situations. Does such reasoning exist?

If anyone could explain why performing the qf here is justifiable from a combinatorial/algebraic perspective, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: The denominator $1-\sqrt{1-4x}$ is divisible by $2x$, so division is possible.

Comment: Are we always allowed to do division in a ring provided that one element divides another? I just assumed that division was only defined as 'multiplying by the multiplicative inverse', but can we somehow extend the notion of division so that this is allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F=\Bbb{Q}((x))$ (the formal Laurent series $\sum_{n\ge -N} a_n x^n$ with rational coefficients) is a field so it works really the same way as over $\Bbb{R}$.

You need to check that the discriminant $1-4x$ of your quadratic polynomial $xT^2-T+1\in F[T]$ has a square root in $F$, which is $$a=\sum_{k\ge 0} {1/2\choose k} (-4x)^k\in F$$

Then $$xT^2-T+1= x(T-\frac{1+a}{2x})(T-\frac{1-a}{2x})\in F[T]$$ $f\in F$ is a root of $xT^2-T+1$ implies either that $f=\frac{1+a}{2x}$ or $f=\frac{1-a}{2x}$.

Comment: Ok, so the idea is that $f$ is more generally only guaranteed to be a formal Laurent series, and it just so happens that the numerator has a factor of $2x$. But since it does, we are able to do a simplification, and show that $f$ is in fact a formal power series. But a priori, all our calculations were taking place over the field of formal Laurent series (as the coefficients). Do I have this right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has positive radius of convergence $R$, for any fixed $x\in(0,\,R)$ we know $f(x)$ is finite, and calculable by the method you've seen. (Note we no longer need to work in a ring of polynomials over a variable.) In particular, continuity at $x=0$ ensures $f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$ for all such $x$.

So the hard question is how we know $R>0$; indeed, the convergence of $f$ for some $x$ of interest is necessary to prove $xf^2-f+1=0$. Alternatively, we can show $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$ generates $\tfrac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ and this satisfies the initial conditions and recursion relation; the worst you can say about this reasoning is that it "got lucky".

Comment: Yes, I suppose this way works, but it just feels disingenuous since there is no way that something as fundamental as the quadratic formula is just 'luckily' working out. It makes it seem to me that there is some general algebraic reasoning which accommodates for the usage of the quadratic formula in this case, and this would explain our 'luck'. In any case, thanks for supporting my claim of analytic justification for the calculation.

Comment: @t42d We get the bestof both worlds if we find some other proof of an exponential upper boundon $c_n$, but unfortunately I can only find proofs, not using the generating function, that get the exact result by some combinatorial argument.